# Parse specific value from internet page using python

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to parse a value called `secu` from pages in the format like: [https://www.ariva.de/[WKN-input]/historische_kurse](https://www.ariva.de/%5BWKN-input%5D/historische_kurse)

I can find in looking at the source code of the page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="secu" value="717816" />
```

E. g.:
https://www.ariva.de/A0D9PT/historische_kurse

In the end I would like to store it to a CSV. This is the code I already have, the parse part is missing:

```
import pandas as pd


# read WKN names from CSV
wkn_list=pd.read_csv('all_wkn_list.csv')

df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['wkn', 'secu'])

# loop through WKNs
i=0
for index, row in wkn_list.iterrows():
    print(row[0])
    url = 'https://www.ariva.de/'+str(row[0])+'/historische_kurse'
    
    # parse secu 
    secu_parsed = "test"
    
    # store wkn and secu
    df_output.loc[i] = [str(row[0])] + [str(secu_parsed)]
    i=i+1

# store WKN + secu to CSV    
df_output.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Use [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to download the HTML then use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML and extract the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the libraries requests and BeautifulSoup for that. Your code would look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
input_element = soup.find('input')
```

There are more ways to find elements based on their tag, class, id... To know more about that, take a look at the BeautifulSoup-documentation.

Comment: Added 'secu_parsed = soup.find("input", {"name":"secu"})['value']' and it works.